# I'm trying to use VBA to click a "Logon" button on a website to automatically logon

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation, ie-automation

I've been trying to submit login credentials automatically with VBA, and I can get the username and password fields to populate, but I can't get the code to click on the logon button. I've tried numerous solutions I've found on here as well as other websites and can't get it to work. Here is my code (I've taken out any attempt to click the button):

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub iTradeLogIn()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
 Dim MyURL As String
 On Error GoTo Err_Clear
 MyURL = "https://www.oms.itradenetwork.com/secure/login/logon.cfm?   _Key=8C049059F2DD44009E"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
 MyBrowser.Silent = True
 MyBrowser.Navigate MyURL
 MyBrowser.Visible = True
 Do
 Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.Document
 HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = "MyName"
 HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = "MyPassword"
'Code Here to click the button


Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Here is some of the source code as well where I think the Logon is:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side';
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

    var tb = new Ext.Toolbar({
        items: [{
            xtype: 'splitbutton',
            id: 'setLanguage',
            text: 'English',

            menu: new Ext.menu.Menu({
            items: [
                    {text: 'English', id: 'EN', handler: changeLanguage},
                    {text: 'Español', id: 'ES', handler: changeLanguage},
                    {text: 'Deutsch', id: 'DE', handler: changeLanguage},
                    {text: 'Français', id: 'FR', handler: changeLanguage},
                    {text: 'Nederlands', id: 'NL', handler: changeLanguage}
                ]
            })
        }, '->', {
            text: 'Logon',
            id: 'Logon',
            disabled: true,
            handler: performLogon,
            formBind: true
        }]
    });

    var logonForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
        labelWidth: 100,
        frame: true,
        title: 'Member Logon',
        id: 'LogonForm',
        bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px 5px 0',
        width: 350,
        defaults: {width: 200},
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        floating: true,
        shadow: 'drop',
        shadowOffset: 15,
        monitorValid: true,
        buttonAlign: 'left',

        items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'User Name',
                id: 'UserName',
                name: 'UserName',
                allowBlank: false,

                maxLength: 50
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                id: 'Password',
                name: 'Password',
                inputType: 'password',
                maxLength: 20
            }, new Ext.form.Checkbox({

                fieldLabel: '',
                labelSeparator: '',
                id: 'RememberMe',
                name: 'RememberMe',
                boxLabel: 'Remember Me?',
                style: 'margin-right: 8px',
                checked: getCookie('REMEMBERME') == "true" ? true : false
            })],

        fbar: tb
```

Comment: This website is created with Sencha framework by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform the click, you only need to call the `Click` method on the Logon button element like this:

```
Call HTMLDoc.all.Logon.Click
```

However, a problem is, that the website only enables the button after you have entered a username and a password. If you try to click the button immediately after filling username and password, this is too early, the button is still disabled, so you need to wait a moment.

In order to wait in VBA, you can import the WinAPI Sleep function like this:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

And then wait for a given number of milliseconds like this:

```
Sleep (500)
```

Combined code:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub Demo()
  Dim MyURL As String
  Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
  Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument

  MyURL = "https://www.oms.itradenetwork.com/secure/login/logon.cfm"
  Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
  MyBrowser.Silent = True
  MyBrowser.Navigate MyURL
  MyBrowser.Visible = True

  Do
    DoEvents
  Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

  Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.Document
  HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = "MyName"
  HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = "MyPassword"

  ' First wait 500ms to give the webite enough time to enable the button
  Sleep (500)
  ' then click the button
  Call HTMLDoc.all.Logon.Click
End Sub
```